# How to solve Jenkins build error on recording test results?

Tags: java, php, testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

After all the successful steps of my Jenkins build I get an error:

Recording test results

> "ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
>   hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?"

I tried to search the answer in Jenkins documentation and on stack-overflow, however I didn't find any answer.

Comment: Check the test reports file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use behat3, then make sure that its version has junit formatter support, as it was missed in early versions https://github.com/Behat/Behat/pull/676

Also check that you have configured profile at behat.yml

behat 2

```
jenkins:  
    formatter:
        name: pretty,junit
        parameters:
            output_path: ,build/logs/behat
```

behat 3

```
jenkins:
    formatters:
        junit: [build/log/behat]
```

Also build.xml must call it as "behat --profile jenkins"

Answer (score 0):

I may assume that you have configured your test result path not to be related to Jenkins workspace (usually, this is the directory which you run tests from). JUnit result xml path should be configured in relation with Jenkins workspace directory, which is the root directory for you xml reports.
[image: your report in workspace]